# $\{g^{-1}(\Omega):\Omega\in\tau_Y\}\in \tau_X$ in topology for continuous functions

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $g: X\rightarrow Y$ be continuous. Let $(X,\tau_X)$ and $(Y,\tau_Y)$ be topological spaces.
Why do we have $\tau=\{g^{-1}(\Omega):\Omega\in\tau_Y\}\subseteq\tau_X$?

My attempt: Let $\Omega\in\tau$. Then $\Omega=g^{-1}(\Omega')$. Since $g$ is continuous we have $\Omega\in\tau$, which seems a little bit too easy for my. Any catches?

Answer (score 0):

No catches: the whole inclusion statement is just a fancy way of re-stating that the inverse image of an open set under a continuous map is open.

Answer (score 0):

This is because if $\Omega \in \tau$ that means there is some $\tilde{\Omega} \in \tau_Y$ such that $g^{-1}(\tilde{\Omega}) = \Omega$.  By definition though we have that $\tilde{\Omega}$ is open in $Y$, so since $g$ is continuous $g^{-1}(\tilde{\Omega})$ is open $X$, or rather $\Omega = g^{-1}(\tilde{\Omega}) \in \tau_X$.